# Access the mutex class in mscorlib.dll

Tags: mutex, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Please correct me if I am wrong or barking up the wrong tree.

There are different `Mutex` classes, one in `mscorlib.Extensions` and one in `mscorlib`. Both come under the `System.Threading` namespace. According [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). I can use the `Mutex` class in `mscorlib`.(Although, the phone symbol does not appear in the column before Name) I basically want to access the `OpenExisting` method from a Windows Phone 7.1 application. The default `System.Threading.Mutex` being used is in `mscorlib.Extensions` which does not have the `OpenExisting` method.

So, the question is, how do I make sure that the `Mutex` class that I access is from the `mscorlib` dll?

Should I un-reference `mscorlib.extensions`, what are the repercussions of doing so?

EDIT 1: Just figured that my application refers `mscorlib[2.0.5.0]` which does not have the `Mutex` class. I was looking at `mscorlib[4.0.0.0]` which has the `Mutex` class. In any case, is there a way for me to access the `OpenExisting` method?

EDIT 2: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6784729/932051) question answers my question about referencing `mscorlib [4.0.0.0]`. So, I cannot use the `OpenExisting` method at all? Is the link to the `Mutex` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), a reference to a wrong class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on [The MSDN Page for Mutex (Silverlight)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) the `OpenExising` method is not available for Silverlight.

So in short: You can't use it.

Comment: Well, I was afraid so. Thanks for the confirmation.